# Показ вводимого текста на странице через инпут

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть простой инпут который принимает текст

```
<input type="text" placeholder="name" />
```

И есть span

```
<span id="name">Alice</span>
```

Есть ли какая-то возможность изменять текст внутри span? Чтобы он менялся на тот текст, который вводит пользователь в input-е?

Comment: Есть. Через свойство `value` получаете значение инпута, через `innerText` вставляете в спан

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let span = document.querySelector('#name');
document.querySelector('#test').addEventListener('input', () => {
  span.textContent = event.target.value;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="name" id="test" />


<span id="name">Alice</span>
```

Comment: Ответ мне нравится, и он работает как я хотел. Но есть маленький баг, когда я ввожу какое-то значение, и удаляю его, у меня поле становится пустым, а должно при удалении возвращаться значение что было(в моём случае Alice)
P.S. Простите, если не указал это в условии

Comment: @FlaceyFurr Добавьте переменную с дефолтным значением....далее внутри функции проверяйте, если value пустое - то в спан пишите дефолтное значение из переменной, в ином случае значение из инпута